# Unexpected Auto Layout Behavior with Large UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm facing an unusual issue with Auto Layout in a UIScrollView setup. Specifically, when a subview's y position exceeds ***2,777,777***, constraints to align other views with it don't seem to work correctly.

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```swift
import UIKit

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {
    private static let theMagicNumber: CGFloat = 2777777

    private let referenceView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: theMagicNumber + 100, width: 40, height: 40)
        return view
    }()

    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size
        return scrollView
    }()

    private lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: Self.theMagicNumber + 500))
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }()

    private let adjacentView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    private let dividerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: theMagicNumber, width: 393, height: 1)
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(referenceView.frame, animated: false)
        createRectBesideScrollView()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(referenceView)
        contentView.addSubview(dividerView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    private func createRectBesideScrollView() {

        view.addSubview(adjacentView)
        adjacentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            adjacentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: referenceView.topAnchor),
            adjacentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: referenceView.bottomAnchor),
            adjacentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: referenceView.trailingAnchor),
            adjacentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: referenceView.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

In this setup, the adjacentView should vertically align with the `referenceView`. However, when running the app, this alignment does not occur as expected, and the y offset is capped to 2,777,777.

[image]

I'm trying to understand the root cause of this issue and am looking for potential solutions or workarounds. Is there a known limitation with Auto Layout constraints for views at very high y positions, and if so, how can I bypass it?

Please note that using frame-based layout for `adjacentView` is not an option for now.

Any insights or advice on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, IMO you should change from frame to constraint (or vice versa) first. Mixing it is not a good solution.

Comment: @son Thanks, but that's my last resort, because it requires a lot of changes for now. I'm exploring ways to achieve it without significant changes. Everything works fine when the scrollView's height is below `2777777` after all.

Comment: @shinhong - there are limits to sizes of UI elements. Not surprising that you run into problems trying to "scroll" that far. What is your actual goal? I assume you're not simply displaying thousands of red and blue boxes.